# To Check multiple criteria before IF & And statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am in complicated situation in which i  have to check multiple criteria and if all those are met then need to compare if a file is sent on Schedule Date and Time and then result should be either "Delayed" or "On time"

In the first step the formula should meet the following criterias

column A2 should be = to Col G2:G11

Column B2 should be = to Col H2:H11

Column C2 should be = to Col I2:I11

If formula meet all these 3 criteria (i.e. a particular file with a particular date and format finds on the ranges mentioned) then we need to compare if a file was sent on schedule date and on schedule time?

e.g. If a file Date 25-Oct-22 was sent on 26-Oct-22 it means answer should be delayed, similarly if a file Date 25-Oct-22 was sent on 25-Oct-22 where the schedule time was 11:00 AM but it was sent on 11:05 AM then the result should be again Delayed, this mean we need to compare that the file sent should be the on same day and before the final scheduled time. this can be compared with following

Currently I have only 1 formula which can check date and time which is mentioned below

=IF(AND(G2<=A2, J2<=D2), "On Time", "Delayed")

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as text table (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. Click here to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as it is easier to copy/paste. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be self contained. Your table should be a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: So what you want is to also check the file format based on the name of the file ?

Comment: Yes, Need to check if a particular file with particular format sent on schedule date and on time

Comment: North-East should not be delayed, it was on time, correct me if i am wrong, also will there be duplicates if so then what is your excel version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a formula like this,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(A2=$G$2:$G$11)*(B2=$H$2:$H$11)*(C2=$I$2:$I$11)*(D2>=$J$2:$J$11),0)),"On Time","Delayed")
```

Comment: Dear @Maykh let me check this

Comment: Sure thing, you need to clarify few things as well, which i have commented above

Comment: @SalmanShafi you can also use a formula with `SUM()` or `SUMPRODUCT()` as well `=IF(SUM((A2=$G$2:$G$11)*(B2=$H$2:$H$11)*(C2=$I$2:$I$11)*(D2>=$J$2:$J$11))>0,"On Time","Delayed")`

Comment: Dear @Maykh let me check new formula you have sent, thanks

Comment: Dear @Maykh let me revise my question, i am still not getting the desired answer, sorry

Comment: @SalmanShafi that formula which I have given should work as per the given conditions, if you are not using MS365 then instead of `SUM()` use `SUMPRODUCT()` I dont understand where it is not working for you. Could you show us a screenshot where it is not working for you

Comment: thanks fo0r the time and attention, i will resend my question with great details again, but first i will try again

Comment: This formula has worked, i have just changed the logic to exact match and it worked. wonderful. Thanks Sir

Comment: Glad to know that it worked for you.